# сложный SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы **posts** и **likes** нужно чтобы  значение **posts.likes** было равно количеству записей в таблице **likes** где **likes.postId** равно **post.id**.
Либо как получить информацию о посте и кол-во лайков одним запросом ?

Comment: И что тут сложного ? `where likes=(select count(1) from likes where likes.postId=post.id)`

Comment: @Mike А можете, пожалуйста, оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никто не помог, но минусов поставили :D

Разобрался сам

```
SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `likes` WHERE postId = id) AS likes FROM `posts`;
```